# Pandas/datetime/total seconds : numpy.timedelta64' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, numpy

I have a data frame.  I converted two of my date columns to datetime format. And I want to calculate the difference in minutes. But I get the following error.

```
from datetime import datetime
df['A'] = df['A'].apply(lambda t: datetime.strptime(t, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
df['B'] = df['B'].apply(lambda t: datetime.strptime(t, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

df['C'] = ((df['B']-df['A']).apply(lambda x:x.total_seconds()/60.))
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.timedelta64' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Small dataset works fine:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['2015-09-01 00:02:34', '2015-09-02 00:02:34'],'B': ['2015-09-02 00:02:34', '2015-09-03 00:02:34']})
df['A'] = df['A'].apply(lambda t: datetime.strptime(t, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
df['B'] = df['B'].apply(lambda t: datetime.strptime(t, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
df['C'] = ((df['B']-df['A']).apply(lambda x:x.total_seconds()/60.))
df
                    A                   B       C
0 2015-09-01 00:02:34 2015-09-02 00:02:34  1440.0
1 2015-09-02 00:02:34 2015-09-03 00:02:34  1440.0
```

For my original big dataset,  If I only select the first two rows of each column and do the same apply function, I would get the same error.

Comment: Could you share some sample of your `df`? Just enough rows to reproduce the error (3 or 4 rows should be enough) :)

Comment: Please see the edit. I do not know what is going on

Comment: Sorry but if you don't have a reproducible example it's impossible for me to find out what's happening. :(

Comment: Understand,  Let me investigate a little bit more.  I will add more information. Thanks for the help

Comment: @MSeifert, it seems if I do this it will work {df['C'] = (df['B'] - df['A'])/ np.timedelta64(1, 's')}.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems I need to do this:

```
df['C'] = (df['B'] - df['A'])/ np.timedelta64(1, 's')
```